# How to keep a fixed distance between two elements while scrolling

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<div class="header__secondary" style="height:40px; background-color:green">
nav1
</div>

<div class="header header--layout-2" style="position: sticky; top: 0; height:40px; background-color:red">
nav2
</div>

<div class="header header--layout-2" style="position: fixed; height:40px; margin-top:20px; background-color:yellow">
elm
</div>

<br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br>
<br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br></br>
```

How can I make the yellow `elm` always have a fixed distance from the `nav2`? The problem is that right now if you scroll down the distance between `nav2` and `elm` will increase because of the `nav1`

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to achieve. Why does nav2 have a `position:sticky`?Can you just make it `position: fixed`?

Comment: @symlink yea, as long as it works they way it's working right now. so the `nav1` and `nav2` are two navbars and i want them to work exactly like they are working right now, i just need the `elm` to always have a fixed/same distance with `nav2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if I understood correctly what you need... but if I did, it should be something like this:

```html
<div class="header__secondary" style="height:40px; background-color:green">
nav1
</div>

<div class="header header--layout-2" style="position: sticky; top: 0; height:40px; background-color:red">
nav2
</div>

<div class="header header--layout-2" style="position: sticky; top: 45px; margin-top: 5px; height: 40px; background-color:yellow">
elm
</div>

<br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br>
<br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br></br>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap elm inside div2 with absolute positioning. Also, assign a top attribute for a fixed distance. Hope it helps.

```html
<div class="header__secondary" style="height:40px; background-color:green">
nav1
</div>
<div class="header header--layout-2" style="position: sticky; top: 0; height:40px; background-color:red">
nav2
<div class="header header--layout-2" style="position:absolute; height:40px;top:70px; background-color:yellow">
elm
</div>


</div>



<br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br>
<br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br><br></br></br>
```